# CSV metadata types disappear in Anypoint Studio

Tags: eclipse, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I have created metadata types in Anypoint Studio 6.2 for JSON schema and CSV file examples. These are always present during my session but when I close Anypoint Studio and reopen, the JSON schema metadata types are still visible but the CSV file metadata types have disappeared and show as unknown Payload where they are used in Transform Message .

How can I stop the CSV metadata types from being lost?

**UPDATED: More info**

I've found that the CSV schema mapping creates a file called **CsvSchema_md_custom_type__.xml** in the folder **catalog\types\custom** and if I remove this section the CSV schema is still visible when I reopen Anypoint Studio

```
<org.mule.tooling.ui.modules.core.metadata.definition.custom.types.CSVSampleSettingsMetadataProperties>
      <sampleFilePath>mappings\CsvSchema.csv</sampleFilePath>
      <delimiter>,</delimiter>
      <rowsToIgnore>0</rowsToIgnore>
      <quotedString>true</quotedString>
      <relativePath>true</relativePath>
      <quoteChar>&quot;</quoteChar>
    </org.mule.tooling.ui.modules.core.metadata.definition.custom.types.CSVSampleSettingsMetadataProperties>
```

Mule version is 3.8.1
Maven version is 3.3.9
Eclipse platform version is 4.5.2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It wont be a big trouble even though you loose your metadata you have created.It will not throw any error. Even though it is missing you would still have the mappings for the transform,so its not an issue.

Comment: I just like having the graphical view of the mappings as it shows a better visual of the object structure and its datatypes. I also lose any CSV field datatypes I've specified and also access to the reader configuration gui. If anyone is maintaining this code then they will see no input to the transformation and will have to load in the file again which just takes time away from doing other things